# hide "new" button on contact tab or lead tab

Tags: button-overrides

is there a way i can hide the "new" button that comes up on the screen when we click on of the Standard object tabs? i am not sure how to go about it after summer'16 disabling home components.i tried doing a jquery and appending it on the visualforce page custom home page component and added it onto the home page layout "narrow left pane" button it doesnt really work.below (i had this code from other post)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function hideButton(){

var url = window.location.href;

var tabUrl = "https://na15.salesforce.com/003/o";

alert('hello taburl is' +tabUrl);

if(url.indexOf(tabUrl) !== -1)

{

var newBtn = $j('[name="new"]');
newBtn.css({"white-space":"normal","display":"none"});

}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to restrict the users from creating records at all? If so, there are better ways. If not, can you give us some more context?

Comment: Currently no way to do it. Best way to handle is override new button with vf page that shows error as appropriate

Comment: @Sebastian ,i cannot have users not create records , they are suppose to create records from contact page related list and not from an object tab,thats the scenario......@Eric - i did that , but when i create the same object from contact related list i get the visualforce page error that i get when creating from object tab

Comment: @user2945545 -  When you click the new button from a parent record on the related child object there is always a param in the URL i.e. `&accid=0011400001xxxxx`. In your VF page, check for that param (or the presence of just retURL being the tab location), if not present then present the error. It is a bit of a hat but it works. If the param is present, redirect them to the standard New page with the `nooverride=1` to bypass the VF page o override

Comment: i started using as but still same thing  <apex:page id="page" standardController="Lead"> <script type="text/javascript">if({!$CurrentPage.parameters.conrel} == '1')  location.replace('/00Q/e?nooverride=1&lookupcon=1&accid={!$CurrentPage.parameters.accid}&conid={!$CurrentPage.parameters.conid}');
 }
    </script>
    <apex:pageMessage severity="ERROR"
    summary etc
        rendered="{! IF(OR($CurrentPage.parameters.conrel = '0',$CurrentPage.parameters.conrel = ''), TRUE, FALSE) }" >
    </apex:pageMessage>
</apex:page>